# Не могу добавить Poetry интерпретатор в Pycharm

Tags: python, poetry

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того как жму на OK. Выскакивает ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полное сообщение об ошибке

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\cleo\application.py", line 327, in run
> exit_code = self._run(io)
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\application.py", line 190, in _run
> exit_code: int = super()._run(io)
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\cleo\application.py", line 431, in _run
> exit_code = self._run_command(command, io)
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\cleo\application.py", line 473, in _run_command
> raise error
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\cleo\application.py", line 454, in *run_command
> self.*event_dispatcher.dispatch(command_event, COMMAND)
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\cleo\events\event_dispatcher.py", line 26, in dispatch
> self.*do_dispatch(listeners, event_name, event)
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\cleo\events\event_dispatcher.py", line 85, in *do_dispatch
> listener(event, event_name, self)
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\application.py", line 283, in configure_env
> from poetry.console.commands.self.self_command import SelfCommand
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\commands\self\self_command.py", line 13, in 
> from poetry.utils.env import EnvManager
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env_*init**.py", line 9, in 
> from poetry.utils.env.base_env import Env
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env\base_env.py", line 15, in 
> from virtualenv.seed.wheels.embed import get_embed_wheel
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_*init**.py", line 3, in 
> from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\run_*init**.py", line 11, in 
> from virtualenv.seed.wheels.periodic_update import manual_upgrade
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels_*init**.py", line 3, in 
> from .acquire import get_wheel, pip_wheel_env_run
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels\acquire.py", line 11, in 
> from .bundle import from_bundle
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels\bundle.py", line 5, in 
> from .periodic_update import periodic_update
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels\periodic_update.py", line 9, in 
> import ssl
> File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in 
> import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: Не найден указанный модуль.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in
> *run_module_as_main
> return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\Scripts\poetry.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in
>    File
> "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\application.py",
> line 411, in main
> exit_code: int = Application().run()   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\cleo\application.py", line
> 338, in run
> self.render_error(e, io)   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\application.py",
> line 180, in render_error
> self.set_solution_provider_repository(self.*get_solution_provider_repository())
> File
> "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\application.py",
> line 400, in *get_solution_provider_repository
> from poetry.mixology.solutions.providers.python_requirement_solution_provider
> import (   File
> "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\mixology\solutions\providers_*init**.py",
> line 3, in 
> from poetry.mixology.solutions.providers.python_requirement_solution_provider
> import (   File
> "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\mixology\solutions\providers\python_requirement_solution_provider.py",
> line 9, in 
> from poetry.puzzle.exceptions import SolverProblemError   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\puzzle_*init**.py",
> line 3, in 
> from poetry.puzzle.solver import Solver   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\puzzle\solver.py",
> line 16, in 
> from poetry.puzzle.provider import Indicator   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\puzzle\provider.py",
> line 27, in 
> from poetry.packages.direct_origin import DirectOrigin   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\packages\direct_origin.py",
> line 10, in 
> from poetry.inspection.info import PackageInfo   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\inspection\info.py",
> line 24, in 
> from poetry.utils.env import EnvCommandError   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env_*init**.py",
> line 10, in 
> from poetry.utils.env.env_manager import EnvManager   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env\env_manager.py",
> line 17, in 
> import virtualenv   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_*init**.py",
> line 3, in 
> from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\run_*init*_.py",
> line 11, in 
> from virtualenv.seed.wheels.periodic_update import manual_upgrade   File
> "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels_*init*_.py",
> line 3, in 
> from .acquire import get_wheel, pip_wheel_env_run   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels\acquire.py",
> line 11, in 
> from .bundle import from_bundle   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels\bundle.py",
> line 5, in 
> from .periodic_update import periodic_update   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels\periodic_update.py",
> line 9, in 
> import ssl   File "C:\Users\483\MiniConda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in 
> import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: Не найден
> указанный модуль.